# Panel with two sections

Tags: html, css

[image: A panel with two sections]

I'm trying to create a panel with two sections, as shown above: a light green section on the left and the dark green wrapped around the light green box.

How can I achieve this? I tried putting a `span` with `inline-block` inside a `div` and tried `height` and `width` properties but it doesn't produce the desired effect.

Comment: Do you mean like in a border?

Comment: Nvm, check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/nuk42du8/4/) what you are after?
Flexbox is realy good for just this, you can read more about flexbox [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: green;
}

.green-box {
  flex: 0;
  min-width: 20px;
  background-color: Chartreuse;
}

.filler {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="green-box">

  </div>
  <div class="filler">
    Icon
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is very close to what i wanted. however i want the border between the inner and outer div to be thinner. how would i achieve that?

Comment: Change the padding of .wrapper to a lower value.

Comment: is there any alternative to doing that? i want to keep the panel big.

Comment: Add padding-top and padding-bottom to .filler

Answer (score 2):

Flexbox can help with this.

1. Create a container with **display: flex property**
2. Create two divs within this container and add a **flex-basis** property to each that equals panel width of 100% or desired number of pixel length

   - E.g. .panel { width = 500px; }, .div1 { flex-basis: 100px; }, .div2 { flex-basis: 400px; }
   - E.g. .panel { width = 100% }, .div { flex-basis: 25%; }, .div2 { flex-basis: 75%; }
3. Style divs (sections) accordingly - height, background-color, border, etc.
4. Within the second div (right section) add your icons and style as well

I used [FontAwesome CDN](https://fontawesome.com/cheatsheet) for the icons. 
Hope this helped, you can also see this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/jenpaulino3/pen/jZaBge) I created.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="div1"></div>
  <div class="div2">
    <i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-sync-alt"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.container div{
  height: 25px;
  width: 100%;
}

.div1{
  background-color:#abffb9;
  flex-basis: 2%;
  border: 1px solid #5cb85b;
}

.div2{
  background-color:#5cb85b;
  flex-basis: 98%;
  text-align: right;
  border: 1px solid #5cb85b;
}

.fas {
  color: #fff;
}
```